# How to retrieve AccessToken in Auth0 for a specific user to deal with a permissioned REST API?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, auth0

I am using [Auth0](https://auth0.com) for User-Authentication in my VueJS-Application.

Now I want to create a backend providing a REST-API that will also use **OAuth2**-protocol and **JWT-tokens** in conjunction with our **Auth0**-based Frontend. This basically means: after SignUp of a new User, I want to send this new User to our backend in order to create a new record *(which is already done)*.

The REST-API will be only accessible with a valid **JWT-Token**, which works perfectly following some tutorials and examples provided by **Auth0** like [this one](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/golang/01-authorization).

I'd like to validate an access_token on my backend with Auth0 for a user, that was authenticated on the frontend application using auth0 also in the backend without sending any passwords.

This way, the Frontend or any other client can obtain an Access-Token like with this `curl`-command:

```
 curl --request POST \
  --url https://dev-xxxxx.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"client_id":"DLjQxxxx","client_secret":"*****","audience":"https://api.example.org","grant_type":"client_credentials"}'
```

On the backend, I am able to parse this token against Auth0 to check if this token is valid or not.

But how can I obtain a token on the Frontend for a specific user consisting of its email and password in Auth0-authentication? The Auth0-API will not return any access token after user authentication that I can use together with my API in order to validate the JWT token for specific roles.

I think I don't get the final workflow here.

Can someone point me please into the right direction?